# Flutter issue - Flutter_driver from sdk depends on file 5.0.6 and flutter_gallery depends on file 5.0.7

Tags: flutter

I got this issue using flutter packages get:

`Because every version of flutter_driver from sdk depends on file 5.0.6 and flutter_gallery depends on file 5.0.7, flutter_driver from sdk is forbidden.
So, because flutter_gallery depends on flutter_driver any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1)`

I don't know what I am supposed to do here, I was trying to compile this flutter example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_gallery

Comment: You might need to switch to a different channel to run `flutter_gallery`. Try `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor`

Comment: I have tried to do that now, but I am not able to run the project, currently, I am getting issues with: DragStartBehavior

Comment: @JosephArriaza i have the same problem

Comment: I didn't make the best solution I guess, I commented the lines that use that Gesture, there are not too much, really, I don't know what that effect does, but it was not needed to run the application, I used this application like a demo.

Answer (score 2):

This may be because flutter dependencies are locked to fixed versions.

You can check this in the ***pubspec.yaml*** for flutter_driver which is in

> \flutter\packages\flutter_driver

and compare it to the latest version at [GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_driver/pubspec.yaml)

If so, **flutter upgrade** won't necessarily update the dependencies versions. Doing a forced update of the packages may resolve your problem.

```
flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
```

Comment: After the forced upgrade, still, the error persists. What I did is changing the version of   `intl to intl: ^0.16.1` in my app, `pubspec.xml`. This resolved my problem. Thanks, by the way.